# How to import from a file with an .mts extension in a CJS-first project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

So I have here a fetchin.mts file:

```
import type { RequestInfo, RequestInit, Response } from "node-fetch";
const importDynamic = new Function("modulePath", "return import(modulePath);")

export async function fetch(url: URL | RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit) : Promise<Response> {
  const {default: fetch} = await importDynamic("node-fetch");
  return fetch(url, init);
}
```

When I try to import the fetch function on another file like this:

```
import {fetch} from "../utils/fetchin.mjs"
```

I get a ts error of :

```
The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("../utils/fetchin.mjs")' call instead.
  To convert this file to an ECMAScript module, change its file extension to '.mts', or add the field `"type": "module"` to '/package.json'.ts(1479)
```

I already tried the suggestion like putting `"type": "module"` on package json but I still can't fix the ts error when importing it to another file and tried researching about this stuffs on google but I can't find any reference about it

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "lib/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "files": ["src/types/modules.d.ts"],
  }
}
```

I also saw some article that I need to downgrade tsconfig/node18 to tsconfig/node16 but I still don't get it. Help guys!

Comment: Did the downgrading work like you are saying?

Comment: Tried it the error was gone but when I try to run it and there are another bunch of errors LMAO

Comment: Lol well that's a good thing I think to have new errors ..

Comment: I think not coz It keeps on getting worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really said what file extension the other file importing `fetch` is using, but I'm going to assume it is a `.ts` extension, and that your package.json is using `"type": "commonjs"` (or not specified, so default to CJS). I'm also going to ignore the use of `ts-node` and focus on `tsc`.

Here is the tsconfig.json (like yours but without the ts-node stuff):

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "lib/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Simple fix is to use `"type": "module"` in your package.json. Then just run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` to get a successful build. I know you said you tried this, but you must have overlooked something because this does in fact work.

If you want to continue using CJS, i.e. `"type": "commonjs"`, then use a dynamic import when importing `fetch` from the `.mts` file.

Lets call the other file `other.ts`:

```
const importFetch = async () => {
  const { fetch } = await import('./fetchin.mjs')
}

importFetch()
```

Now run `tsc` again like before to get a successful build, or run `ts-node other.ts`. This is by the way exactly what the error message was suggesting.